template implicit instantiation generating member definitions as from primary template
What I understood from the standard (I refer to the text from n4849 draft)
(§13.9.1-2) [temp.inst]
The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
(2.1) — the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, of the non-deleted class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and friends; and
(2.2) — the implicit instantiation of the definitions of deleted member functions, unscoped member enumerations, and member anonymous unions.
(§13.9.2-11) [temp.explicit]
An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members (not including members inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, ....
is that an implicit instantiation leads to use the declarations of the members of class template as from the primary template (or a better matching partial specialization),
whereas an explicit instantiation leads to use both declaration and definition (or a better matching partial specialization or an explicit specialization) but only the declaration in case of members template.
Now, everything seems clear in the following example 1:
template<class T1> class A1 {
    template<class T2> class B{
        void func();
    };
};

/*
// this would solve, providing a specialization of B for A1<char>,
//with or without keeping the next explicit instantiation

template<> class A1<char>{
    template<class T2> class B{
        void func(); // of course, func2 (different) name may be used,
                     // to be replicated in last line of code of this example
    };
}

*/

// explicit instantiation not producing any definition for B from the primary template
template class A1<char>;

template<> template<class T2> void A1<char>::B<T2>::func(){};
// error because the template B is not yet defined for the specialization A1<char>,
// and the same would happen also after removing the explicit instantiation,
// as also the consequent implicit instantiation provided by "A1<char>" in
// this line of code does not push to generate the definition of
// the template class B inside A1 for the specialization A1<char>.

But I have doubts in the following example 2:
template<class T1> class A2 {
    class B{
        void func();
    };
};

//template class A2<char>;

template<> void A2<char>::B::func(){};

this example compiles even without the explicit instantiation.
How this may happen ? That is, what causes the definition of the class B for the specialization A2<char> ? Mainly, where in the standard is there a rule to clarify it ?

Defining void A1<char>::B<int>::func() also works Demo

I can't say for sure, but I have a feeling it's kinda similar to function name resolution. Since in a second example B is not a template (and also non-dependent) its definitions is immediately available, regardless of where it's been declared.

@Jarod42, from the Demo I see you have elaborated example 1, and this means that in both cases, for class template member, or class member, the definition coming from the primary template is instantiated for some motivation.
I am looking for the standard rule that make both possible, or a more-general interpretation of the rules I have posted above.
Any idea ?

@Dmitry, thank you for your contribute. However, I am trying to find the match between the standard rules and the experimented behavior. Is there for example anywhere stated that we may directly refer a nested specialization, which leads the definition from the generic template to be instantiated ?

@user20575107 this says the name of the nested class referenced as a member of the current instantiation. I suppose it does imply that you can access B from A2<char> (cause it is the same as accessing a member for instance). Nested class in the standard is referred to non-template class only (otherwise it would be something like nested class template)

thank you @Dmitry, but your text focuses about the current instantiation. In parts [temp.inst], [temp.explicit], etc., the text always separates 'class member' and 'class template member', but I agree somewhere there may be the key with 'class member' as including both.... but the point remains: where ? The only examples I could see in the standard text use an explicit specialization, e.g. in §13.9.3-6 in the draft n4849 for C++20 with template<> struct A<char>::B { void f(); }; first and then void A<char>::B::f() { /* ... */ }.

Maybe an implicit rule meant by the standard commettee is that in both examples, with either A::B or A::B, by referring to B or B, is like to push declaration (or definition, too, for explicit instantiation) to be instantiated, exactly like it happens for the enclosing template -> looking for them within the current namespace, which would be within "A name-space". It would make sense, but a clear rule would be (or have been) better. Please, let me know whether you find such a written rule, or whether you agree with the point of view.

However, I believe that the portion of the text from §13.9.1-1 [temp.inst], "If a class template has been declared, but not defined, at the point of instantiation (13.8.4.1), the instantiation yields an incomplete class type", formally means that A::B should not work in the first example, as the implicit instantiation of A does not instantiate the definition of the nested template class B. I see that this point of view leads the definitions of the nested class templates provided within the primary templates to be impossible to use. Where the standard states differently ?

My last opinion: [temp.inst] §13.9.1-1 (discussed above) does not apply to class template members, whereas §13.9.1-3 applies ("... member of a class template or a member template ...") and such clause does not require for a definition to be already present. However, the standard should be then clarified that, if no definition is present, then it is possible to 'recovery' from the non-instantiated definition when the enclosing template (specialization) was instantiated, referring the possible postponed definition instantiation also in §13.9.1-(2.1) and [temp.explicit] §13.9.2-11.
